# Trying to extract 5 characters from a column when adding record mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, post, split

My `part_no` column has the following format:  `000-00000-00` for all records.

I need to extract the five middle characters from `part_no` and place it in the `core` column when I create the record.

I can't get my script to work.

I'm not getting any errors.  Just not working.

```
$order = "INSERT INTO cartons_added (add_time, type, part_no, add_type, add_qty, add_ref, add_by, add_notes)
        VALUES
        ('$date',
        '$_POST[type]', 
        '$_POST[part_no]', 
        '$_POST[add_type]', 
        '$_POST[add_qty]', 
        '$_POST[add_ref]', 
        '$_POST[add_by]', 
        '$_POST[add_notes]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);
$query2 = "select part_no from cartons_current";
$sel = mysql_query($query2);
$res = mysql_result($sel);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $core_digits = split('-',$row[0]);
    $core =$core_digits[1];
    $query3 = "insert  into cartons_current(core) values($core)";
    $sel2 = mysql_query($query3);
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. [Read this asap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please tell us the structure of your `cartons_current` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the script has no error.

I think the problem is on your SQL that made you can't insert a new row, specifically on the table structure. Maybe you defined a `PRIMARY KEY` without `AUTO_INCREMENT`, defined a `INDEX` or `UNIQUE` key that is not the `core` key or there have some other key that did not have default value. Remember that you can't insert a row without defining all required field.

You script is selecting all `part_no` and for every `part_no` you are inserting a new row in the same table, so maybe there is the problem.

I think what you want is update every result to add they `core` value, you can do that with `UPDATE` as this code:

```
function getValue($value) {
  return "'" . trim(mysql_real_escape_string($value)) . "'";
}

mysql_query('INSERT INTO `cartons_added` (`add_time`, `type`, `part_no`, `add_type`, `add_qty`, `add_ref`, `add_by`, `add_notes`)
             VALUES (' . 
              getValue($date) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[type]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[part_no]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[add_type]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[add_qty]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[add_ref]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[add_by]) . ', ' .
              getValue($_POST[add_notes]) . 
             ')');

$partNoQuery = mysql_query('SELECT `part_no` FROM `cartons_current`');

while($partNoResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($partNoQuery)) {
    list($prefix, $core, $suffix) = explode('-', $partNoResult['part_no']);
    mysql_query('UPDATE cartons_current SET `core` = \'' . $core . '\' WHERE `part_no` = \'' . $partNoResult['part_no'] . '\'');
}
```

I added getValue function to escape posted data to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `cartons_current` table based on your `cartons_added` table with something like:

```
INSERT INTO cartons_current(core) 
SELECT SUBSTR(part_no, 5, 5) FROM cartons_added
```

You will probably want to limit that with a `WHERE` clause or maybe deal with what happens when this value is already in `cartons_current` (use either `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this

```
$res = mysql_result($sel);
```

And change your `while` to reference the main query resource

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sel)) {
```

I don't understand your logic with your tables though.  You're inserting data into the `cartons_added` table but then you're selecting from `cartons_current`?

Also, [`split`](http://php.net/split) is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You said five middle "characters", so I'd add quotes around your variable like so:

```
$query3 = "insert  into cartons_current(core) values('$core')";
```

*(Also, there's only about a gazillion answers on SO about SQL injection, and using pdo)*

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO cartons_current(core) 
SELECT 
  substr(part_no,position('-' IN part_no)+1,position('-' IN substr(part_no,position('-' IN part_no)+1))-1)
FROM cartons_added;
```

Comment: This is pretty good. Although an ugly query, it accounts for the possibility that the format of `part_no` may change slightly.

Comment: The query gets slightly less ugly if you remember, that MySQL will calculate each function oly once per row, i.e. `substr(part_no,position('-' IN part_no)` will be calculated only once, although it is used 3 times

Comment: I mean it's not so easy on the eyes (this can't be helped, it's SQL) not that it would give bad performance. I'm not criticizing, this is actually a very good way to do it.